# Remove empty or whitespace strings from array - Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex, string, filter

I've found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19888749/4341456) beautiful method for removing empty strings - `arr = arr.filter(Boolean)`.

But it doesn't seem to work on whitespace strings.

```
var arr = ['Apple', '  ', 'Mango', '', 'Banana', ' ', 'Strawberry'];
arr = arr.filter(Boolean);
// ["Apple", "  ", "Mango", "Banana", " ", "Strawberry"]

// should be ["Apple", "Mango", "Banana", "Strawberry"]
```

Is there a nice way to expand this method to removing whitespaces as well or should i trim the whitespaces by iterating the array first?

Answer (score 67, accepted):

`filter` works, but you need the right predicate function, which `Boolean` isn't (for this purpose):

```
// Example 1 - Using String#trim (added in ES2015, needs polyfilling in outdated
// environments like IE)
arr = arr.filter(function(entry) { return entry.trim() != ''; });
```

or

```
// Example 2 - Using a regular expression instead of String#trim
arr = arr.filter(function(entry) { return /\S/.test(entry); });
```

(`\S` means "a non-whitespace character," so `/\S/.test(...)` checks if a string contains at least one non-whitespace char.)

or (perhaps a bit overboard and harder to read)

```
// Example 3
var rex = /\S/;
arr = arr.filter(rex.test.bind(rex));
```

---

With an ES2015 (aka ES6) arrow function, that's even more concise:

```
// Example 4
arr = arr.filter(entry => entry.trim() != '');
```

or

```
// Example 5
arr = arr.filter(entry => /\S/.test(entry));
```

---

**Live Examples** -- The ES5 and earlier ones:

```js
var arr = ['Apple', '  ', 'Mango', '', 'Banana', ' ', 'Strawberry'];
console.log("Example 1: " + JSON.stringify(arr.filter(function(entry) { return entry.trim() != ''; })));
console.log("Example 2: " + JSON.stringify(arr.filter(function(entry) { return /\S/.test(entry); })));
var rex = /\S/;
console.log("Example 3: " + JSON.stringify(arr.filter(rex.test.bind(rex))));
```

...and the ES2015 (ES6) ones *(won't work if your browser doesn't support arrow functions yet)*:

```js
var arr = ['Apple', '  ', 'Mango', '', 'Banana', ' ', 'Strawberry'];
console.log("Example 4: " + JSON.stringify(arr.filter(entry => !entry.trim() == '')));
console.log("Example 5: " + JSON.stringify(arr.filter(entry => /\S/.test(entry))));
```

Comment: It's slightly cleaner to say `!/\S/.test(entry)`.

Comment: @torazaburo: Actually, **all** of my examples were backward!

Comment: @Daniel: Classic morning mental fail. Fixed. :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder : Is there a reason why your first/second example would not remove the first element of an array if that contained just a single whitespace character?

Comment: @user3001499: No, why?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder - I have a script where I have used this example, the first element is a single whitespace character and it isn't being removed (all subsequent whitespace elements are though). I wondered if it's a bug elsewhere in my code or an idiosyncrasy of this method. Must be a bug on my part!

Comment: I got an error with example 1 `Execution failed: TypeError: Cannot find function trim in object `. Example 2 worked for my purposes.

Comment: @DaniloCuellar - Sounds like you're running the code in an outdated environment (like IE). `trim` was added to strings in ES2015. It can be easily polyfilled if needed.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I'm on Chrome. Either way, example 2 is working for me. I appreciate it.

Comment: @DaniloCuellar - That tells me that `entry` isn't a string in your scenario. Passing a non-string into `test` will convert it to a string.

Answer (score 22):

You can take advantage of empty string as falsy value.

You can use [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) with [`String#trim`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim).

Using ES6 Arrow function:

```
arr = arr.filter(e => String(e).trim());
```

```js
var arr = ['Apple', '  ', 'Mango', '', 'Banana', ' ', 'Strawberry'];
var nonEmpty = arr.filter(e => String(e).trim());

document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(nonEmpty, 0, 4);
```

```html
<pre id="result"></pre>
```

Using ES5 anonymous function:

```
arr = arr.filter(function(e) {
    return String(e).trim();
});
```

```js
var arr = ['Apple', '  ', 'Mango', '', 'Banana', ' ', 'Strawberry'];
var nonEmpty = arr.filter(function(e) {
    return String(e).trim();
});

document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(nonEmpty, 0, 4);
```

```html
<pre id="result"></pre>
```

Comment: I'd use `String(e).trim()`, just in case.

Comment: @agm1984 Because OP only wants to remove empty and the string containing only spaces, I've used `trim`. If you want to keep only truthy values you may use `.filter(e => e)`.

Comment: Thanks, I removed my answer after further evaluation.

Comment: Good answer, saved my day. You can never be sure that everything in the array is a `String`.

Answer (score 5):

Based on [this MDN reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp):

> `\s`
>   Matches a single white space character, including space, tab, form feed, line feed and other Unicode spaces. Equivalent to `[ \f\n\r\t\v​\u00a0\u1680​\u180e\u2000​-\u200a​\u2028\u2029\u202f\u205f​\u3000\ufeff]`.

And on [ECMA 262 reference](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.10.2.12), saying `\s` should match ["White Space"](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-7.2) like `\u0009` (Tab, `<TAB>`), `\u000B` (Vertical Tab, `<VT>`), `\u000C` (Form Feed, `<FF>`), `\u0020` (Space, `<SP>`), `\u00A0` (No-break space, `<NBSP>`), `\uFEFF` (Byte Order Mark, `<BOM>`), and other category “Zs” (`<USP>`), and also ["line terminators"](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-7.3) like `\u000A` (Line Feed, `<LF>`), `\u000D` (Carriage Return, `<CR>`), `\u2028` (Line separator, `<LS>`) and `\u2029` (Paragraph separator, `<PS>`), you can use the following code to remove elements that are either empty or whitespace only if `trim()` is not natively available:

```js
var arr = ['Apple', '  ', 'Mango', '', 'Banana', ' ', 'Strawberry'];
arr = arr.filter(s => s.replace(/\s+/g, '').length !== 0);
// Or for ES5
// arr = arr.filter(function (el) { return el.replace(/\s+/g, '').length !== 0; });
console.log(arr);
```

In case some old browsers behave differently with `\s`, replace it with `[ \f\n\r\t\v​\u00a0\u1680​\u180e\u2000​-\u200a​\u2028\u2029\u202f\u205f​\u3000\ufeff]` character class:

```
arr = arr.filter(function (el) { return el.replace(/[ \f\n\r\t\v​\u00a0\u1680​\u180e\u2000​-\u200a​\u2028\u2029\u202f\u205f​\u3000\ufeff]+/g, '').length !== 0; });
```

And you can also customize it further to include new Unicode spaces to come.

Comment: I would just use `\s`, but [MDN `trim()` reference page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim) suggests this regexp. If we really need to support *all* Unicode whitespace, we'd need to add more characters to the character class.

Comment: But doesn't `\s` include `\xA0` (and couldn't that be written more simply as `\n`)?

Comment: MDN is written by mere mortals and should not be considered holy writ. It is very clear that `\s` includes `\n`, which is the same as `\x0a`. So the regexp given on that MDN page is wrong, or at least redundant.

Comment: @torazaburo: It seems you are right, though `\x0A` matches a hard space (not a  newline). I think I need to ransack the ECMAScript documentation to check that.

Comment: I don't know what "hard space" means. According to MDN regexp page, "\n Matches a line feed (U+000A)."

Comment: @torazaburo: `\xA0` != `\x0A`, "hard" = "nonbreaking". BTW, *MDN is written by mere mortals* means there is some reference written by the gods? :) Would you mind sharing a link?

Comment: Sorry about my dyslexic confusion. But the fact remains that `\s` apparently DOES include `\xa0` (non-breaking space).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: Still mere mortals, but with a more robust review process: [The specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-characterclassescape), which tells us that `\s` matches [everything here](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-white-space) and [everything here](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-line-terminators). Which includes `\xA0` and all other Unicode space chars. For at least some time, several implementations in the wild failed to follow the spec, which is probably why MDN says that.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: I have just found that: http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-7.2

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: Yup, but `\s` also matches line terminators. That's the old spec, but this part didn't change (in substance; just presentation).

Comment: Yeah, I added all the relevant details to the answer. I hope it is now complete and helpful to those who seek understanding what is behind `\s` :)

Answer (score 0):

You Can try this [approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20668919/11181109). I found this process simple and it work for me.

```js
let arrayEle = ["abc", " "," ", "def", "xyz", " "]; 

  arrayEle = arrayEle.filter((element) => {
    return /\S/.test(element);
  });
  
  console.log(arrayEle);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

> #### const fruits = ['Apple', undefined, '  ', 'Mango', '', 'Banana', ' ', 'Strawberry'];
>
> #### fruits.filter(fruit => fruit && fruit.trim())

Output: ["Apple", "Mango", "Banana", "Strawberry"]

```
Filter condition: fruit && fruit.trim()

prefix - will remove all the falsy value
suffix - will trim and then remove all the falsy values
```

Answer (score 0):

A one-line solution written in ES6 for quick use:

```js
const filterArray=a=>a.filter(x=>typeof x!=='string'||!!x.trim())
```

Some advantages of this are that it ignores anything that is not a string.

Without ES6:

```js
function filterArray(a) {
  return a.filter(function(x) {
    return typeof x !== 'string' || !!x.trim()
  })
}
```

Example:

```js
const filterArray=a=>a.filter(x=>typeof x!=='string'||!!x.trim())

console.log(filterArray([1, 2, 4, '', '']))
```

Or if your browser doesn't support ES6 (which it probably does):

```js
function filterArray(a) {
  return a.filter(function(x) {
    return typeof x !== 'string' || !!x.trim()
  })
}

console.log(filterArray([1, 2, 4, '', '']))
```

Answer (score 0):

I used filter and checking if element length is not equal to zero.
It worked for me, and this solution is short:

```js
const arr = ['Apple', '', 'Mango', '', 'Banana', '', 'Strawberry']

const arr2 = arr.filter(item => item.length !== 0)          

console.log(arr2)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function clearSpace(arr){
    for (var key in arr) {
        if (arr[key] == "") {
            arr.splice(key, 1)
            clearSpace(arr)
        }
    }
}
var arr = ["","a","b","",""]
clearSpace(arr)
console.log(arr)

//I hope this helps you!!
//Vu Tien Luong - 3GTEL
```

Answer (score -1):

Could use `Array.protype.join()`, `String.prototype.split()` with parameter `RegExp` `/\s|,/` followed by `.filter(Boolean)`

```js
var arr = ['Apple', '  ', 'Mango', '', 'Banana', ' ', 'Strawberry'];
arr = arr.join().split(/\s|,/).filter(Boolean);
console.log(arr)
```

Comment: This is a horrible idea. What if an element in the array contains internal whitespace, like `"My name is Guest271314"`, or a comma?

Comment: @torazaburo `["My name is a b c", 'Apple', '  ', 'Mango', '', 'Banana', ' ', 'Strawberry'].join("~").split(/~\s+~|\s(?=\s+)|~?~/)`

Comment: Now it won't work if the strings in the array have a tilde in them.

Comment: @torazaburo `["My name is, a b c", "Apple", " ", "Mango", "", "Banana", " ", "Strawberry"].join("  "/* two space characters */).replace(/\s{2,}/g, "DELIM").split("DELIM")`