# How import data from gmail txt attachment into google sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, txt

I receive a daily email with a .txt attachment and I wrote a script that gets finds the file and brings it into a Google sheet which I hope to run on a daily trigger.

I used someone else's script that oringinally had a .csv file as the attachment.  How do I make it work for a txt file with a "~" delimiter????

```
function importsearchresultsTXTFromGmail() {

var threads = GmailApp.search("from:****@erusd.org");
var messages = threads[0].getMessages();
var message = messages[messages.length - 1];
var attachment = message.getAttachments()[0];

// Is the attachment a TXT/CSV file

attachment.setContentType('text');
//attachment.setContentTypeFromExtension();

if (attachment.getContentType() === "text") {

var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sh0 = sheet.getSheetByName("Data")
var csvData = Utilities.parsecsv(attachment.getDataAsString(), "~");


// Remember to clear the content of the sheet before importing new data
sh0.getRange(3, 1, csvData.length, csvData[0].length).setValues(csvData);
GmailApp.markMessageRead(message);

}
}
```

Comment: It seems as though you have already answered your own question so what else is the problem.  Are you getting an error and if so what is the exact error message.  You many need to check your execution logs.

Comment: I am with @Cooper with this one. Though I want to clarify 2 things about this first is about the type of data. If this was a txt file, you can just get directly with getDataAsString function I think you there are more things in your use case that you might have overlooked to share. Can you share what does the "\~" represents in your files, is it about the file name or the text inside the files. If possible can you include on your post the sample Data Set, Use Case and a more defined explanation of your expected result.

Comment: Thank you both for responding... I am getting several errors... Error#1: https://drive.google.com/file/d/12up9tXO5-ifnVeHuqU24kWM-8vG1O60d/view?usp=drive_link Error#2: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1h5Nh0R-fc5ZP6evjNsgA4y3T0epQ5s7a/view?usp=drive_link Link to Google Sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1H4hxfKm3Ru8QgOi7J3rP9QRgaZjCZHsydQU7sotJ5tA/edit?usp=sharing  Link to txt file sample: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1EfEM8b3-QO1V-37VEYKqjEMpo3syfwySugDDmRhCNhg/edit?usp=drive_link

Comment: Thank you for responding Heather, can you share the files to the public? I believe that access was not granted with everyone on your files for them to be viewed, to your sheet. I was actually looking about your expected result how your data should look like when it is done being processed by the script can do you think can you add them manually for better oversight on your project.

Comment: Ok this is how the data should look like... link:https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1H4hxfKm3Ru8QgOi7J3rP9QRgaZjCZHsydQU7sotJ5tA/edit#gid=386153571

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Getting Attachment on Gmail, Process TXT and Paste to Google Sheets

Thank you for continuously responding. There are 3 parts in this code. Which Highlighted on the comments on the code. Please make sure to read it so you can adjust the values as well accordingly. Getting TXT doesn't need to be parsed, you can use it directly by getting it as a string. Structuring the Data is really crucial with Google Sheet.

### Sample Code:

```
function importsearchresultsTXTFromGmail() {
var dataToPaste = [];
var threads = GmailApp.search("sample@yourdomain.com");
var messages = threads[0].getMessages();
var message = messages[messages.length - 1];
var attachment = message.getAttachments()[0];
/* I copied your parameters on getting your desired attachment please feel free to change it depending on your needs*/

//Getting the content directly from the text file no need to parse it.
content = attachment.getDataAsString();


// I am just getting your active Spreadsheet, please change the Sheet Name accordingly

var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");

// In this part I have split and remove unneccesarry parts of your array based on your sample data

var splittedArr = content.split("~");
splittedArr.pop();

// Your sample data set has 24 elements, so I have change chunk one whole array to cover per row pasting of data
for(var i = 0; i < splittedArr.length; i += 24){
  dataToPaste.push(splittedArr.slice(i,i + 24))
}

// Getting the structure of resulting array and pasting the data as 2D array to be handled by sheet.
var range = sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow()+ 1, 1, dataToPaste.length, dataToPaste[0].length)
range.setValues(dataToPaste);
}
```

### How the result Looks Like:

[image]

## References:

[Gmail Attachments || getDataAsString()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-attachment#getdataasstring)

[Array Split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)

[Google Sheet || setValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluesvalues)

Comment: If this answers your question, please click the accept button on the left (check icon) and upvoting the answer.  By doing so, other people in the community, who may have the same concern as you, will know that theirs can be resolved.  If the accept button is unavailable to you, feel free to tell me. [how to accept the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)

Comment: This worked perfectly and your sample code helped me to understand each line of code. I can NOT thank you and this community enough!

Comment: Babanana, I have one more question... will this import overwrite the data in the Google sheet that was imported from the previous running of the script?

Comment: the script is adding a space or 'return' space to each of my rows which is making the xlook up I have running not find the data in the first column of the row... help??  Does it have something to do with this part of the code? 
// Your sample data set has 24 elements, so I have change chunk one whole array to cover per row pasting of data
for(var i = 0; i < splittedArr.length; i += 24){
  dataToPaste.push(splittedArr.slice(i,i + 24))
}
var range = sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow()+ 1, 1, dataToPaste.length, dataToPaste[0].length)
range.setValues(dataToPaste);
}

Comment: You are welcome Heather. This code will not overwrite anything it will just add on the last row. There is no adding of space that was included on the code however there was always a whitespace that was included on the data set that I did not remove to copy your expected results structure. If you are looking to do that this case could be helpful to you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20668872/remove-whitespace-only-array-elements if you need more help with another thing don't hesitate to post a question I am sure that the community will be happy to help you.

Comment: is there easy code to add to clear the sheet before importing new data from txt file?

Comment: clearContents(), is the way for deleting whole sheet so you can start fresh. In the code I have provided. You can use sheet.clearContents();. You can add this below the declaration of the sheet just below var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");